# python dict append values to dataframe after adding a row for dict keys

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a dictionary where the keys are GitHub repository names and the values contain JSON-formatted data.

ex:

```json
    {'r1':[
       {'id': 1178421030,
       'name': 'x',
        },
       {'id': 1178420990,
       'name': 'y',
       }],
    'r2':[
       {'id': 1178421031,
       'name': 'a',
        },
       {'id': 1178420950,
       'name': 'b',
       }]
    }
```

I can create a dataframe from the JSON the values in the dict using:

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
for i in responses:
    
    df=df.append(pd.json_normalize(responses[i]))
```

This gives me a df that looks like this:

```
   id              name
 1178421030           x
 1178420990           y 
 1178421031           a
 1178420950           b
```

I want the keys of the dict as another column named `repo_name` in the df, something like:

```
   id              name       repo_name
 1178421030           x          r1
 1178420990           y          r1
 1178421031           a          r2   
 1178420950           b          r2
```

how shall I go about doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict); it should allow you more control over your data collection :

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in data.items():
    for entry in value:
        d["id"].append(entry["id"])
        d["name"].append(entry["name"])
        d["repo_name"].append(key)

d

defaultdict(list,
            {'id': [1178421030, 1178420990, 1178421031, 1178420950],
             'name': ['x', 'y', 'a', 'b'],
             'repo_name': ['r1', 'r1', 'r2', 'r2']})
```

Create dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(d)

      id      name  repo_name
0   1178421030  x   r1
1   1178420990  y   r1
2   1178421031  a   r2
3   1178420950  b   r2
```

Another option would be to use [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) in a list comprehension:

```
pd.concat(pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=[key]).assign(repo_name=key) 
          for key in data)
```

Answer (score 2):

let's say your JSON is called "d"

```
   data=pd.DataFrame()
   for i in d.keys():
        z=pd.DataFrame(d[i])
        z['repo_name']=i
        data=pd.concat([data,z])



           id name repo_name
0  1178421030    x        r1
1  1178420990    y        r1
0  1178421031    a        r2
1  1178420950    b        r2
```